# How to track the animation frame count in kinetic.js?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

This is my code :

```
var playerTimerGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
  x:420,
  y:350
});

var animations = {
    idle: [{
      x: 408,
      y: 1420,
      width: 55,
      height: 55
    }, {
      x: 463,
      y: 1420,
      width: 55,
      height: 55
    }, {
      x: 518,
      y: 1420,
      width: 55,
      height: 55
    }, {
      x: 573,
      y: 1420,
      width: 55,
      height: 55
    }, {
      x: 628,
      y: 1420,
      width: 55,
      height: 55
    }]
  };

  var timer = new Kinetic.Sprite({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      image: SpriteImaage,
      animation: 'idle',
      animations: animations,
      frameRate: 7,
      index: 0
    });

  playerTimerGroup.add(timer);
  layer.add(playerTimerGroup);
  stage.add(self.layer);
  timer.start();
```

Here i want to show a text (seconds) which keep changing for every frame.
How to achieve this ?

(I mean when first animation start I want to show 1, on second I want to show 2 and so on... till last animation.)

I tried this :

```
  _.each(animations.idle, function(value, index){
      timer.afterFrame(index, function(){
        console.log(index);
      });
  });
```

but this runs only for last index..
any way to bind timer.afterFrame for every index or call timer.afterFrame for every index ?

Comment: You can try calling afterFrame for every frame index...  From a quick browse of the docs I don't see another way.

Comment: tried that also but it always called for last element only. got another way of doing it. posted below. Thanks alot for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var playerTimerGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
  x: 420,
  y: 350
});

var animations = {
  idle: [{
    x: 408,
    y: 1420,
    width: 55,
    height: 55
  }, {
    x: 463,
    y: 1420,
    width: 55,
    height: 55
  }, {
    x: 518,
    y: 1420,
    width: 55,
    height: 55
  }, {
    x: 573,
    y: 1420,
    width: 55,
    height: 55
  }, {
    x: 628,
    y: 1420,
    width: 55,
    height: 55
  }]
};

var timer = new Kinetic.Sprite({
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  image: SpriteImaage,
  animation: 'idle',
  animations: animations,
  frameRate: 1,
  index: 0
});
```

creating a text object here, which will change on every second:

```
var timerText = new Kinetic.Text({
  x: 15,
  y: 15,
  text: '20',
  fontSize: 25,
  fontFamily: 'Calibri',
  fill: 'white'
});

i = 1;

time = 0;
```

creating an animation object here which will change the text on every second:

```
var timerTextAnimation = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
  timerText.setText(i);
  if (frame.time - time >= 1000) {
    i++;
    time = frame.time;
  }
}, layer);

timerTextAnimation.start();

playerTimerGroup.add(timer);
playerTimerGroup.add(timerText);
layer.add(playerTimerGroup);
stage.add(self.layer);
timer.start();
```

stopping all the animations here:

```
timer.afterFrame(animations.idle.length - 1, function() {
  timer.stop();
  timerTextAnimation.stop();
});
```

This works for me.
hope it also helps others.